# Sequoia Park Visit

Tags: children, california, national-parks

I am traveling with my brother, his wife and my niece (7 years old)

We start in San Francisco, and we plan to visit Yosemite (2 nights) and them Sequoia Park and drive to Los Angeles.
We will be in Sequoia Park one day. Not sure where to sleep (town) or how to plan this visit. What do you recommend to do knowing I am going with my niece seven years old.

Is Sequoia park access to "General Sherman Tree" a hike? Or Can I stop the car closeby and walk for 10 minutes to the area?

Comment: Welcome back to TSE. As a reminder, however, as elsewhere on Stack Exchange, you are expected to avoid open-ended and subjective questions, and to demonstrate your initial research efforts. At this point you should be consulting guide books, travel blogs, the NPS website, and so forth, returning here to fine-tune your choices. Where to go and whether a hike is "long" or not depends entirely on an individual's priorities, tastes, experience, and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://www.nps.gov/seki/learn/nature/sherman.htm, there is a "Main Trail" and an "Accessible Trail".  The Main Trail is 1/2 mile long.  An adult walking briskly could probably do it in 10 minutes but I don't know how fast your niece walks.

The Accessible Trail is only described as "short".  Based on the [Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/General+Sherman+Tree/@36.5820341,-118.7505203,17.75z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xb22679c5c07e9188!8m2!3d36.5817069!4d-118.751442) it appears to be about 1000 feet.  However, you cannot park there unless you have a disability parking placard.  You can ride a [shuttle](https://www.nps.gov/seki/planyourvisit/parktransit.htm) there from late May to early September.

Comment: thanks for the answer exactly what I needed to know.